# Removed unpacked gems folders, now gettings errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rubygems, freeze, unpack

I unpacked gems and then removed them manually with "rm".  Now I can't get it to use system gems and I get errors with everything I do.

I had unpacked shoulda and froze rails, then later decided it wasn't necessary and deleted the shoulda folder and all the action_/active_ folders (I reset to HEAD and discarded the changes).  I can't think of where there would have been a change that's still reflecting an unpack/freeze...

Now when I try to run rake I get:

```
no such file to load -- app_name/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer
```

Is there a way to get it back to using the system gems?  I don't see why it doesn't just go by precedence and load the system gems if ones in vendor/plugins/ aren't present.

Any insight would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, figured out a way around this problem:

I just created a new rails app, gave it shoulda as a gem dependency, then unpacked the gems and froze rails.  Then I just copied the folders vendor/gems/ and vendor/rails/ over to my actual app, and everything works.  Now I just have to use actual rails commands this time (like rake rails:unfreeze).